# Arduino uno wifi rev2 stuck inside loop

Tags: loop, arduino-uno-wifi

It might be a stupid question but I can't figure it out. While running the code below. I want to open the box when the code matches the code in API. This all works. I can even close the box afterwords. But then I am stuck inside my loop. after the box is closed I want the screen to say box closed and then I want the void loop() to start again. so my screen asks for a code again. I tried using break and exit but no luck so far. 
entire code:

```
/* hardware libraries*/
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>

/*Wifi and request libraries*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW 0x0

/* wifi credentials*/
char ssid[] = "ssid";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "password";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char server[] = "parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu";
// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); // lcd object
Servo myservo; //servo object
boolean boxOpenend = false ;

/* Keypad*/
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7};

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
String value = "";

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(); //start lcd
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(A0); // attach servo to pin
  lcd.backlight(); // start screen light

  /* connect to wifi */
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
}

void loop() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Geef bestelcode");
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();   // get the key pressed
  value = value + String(customKey);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(value);
  if (customKey == '#') {

    String response_Status = "";
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

      value.remove(16);
      Serial.println(value);
      Serial.println("connected to server");

      // Make a HTTP request:
      client.println("GET /api/boxes/1444/code/" + value + " HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
    }
    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonBuffer;

    while (client.connected()) {

      String response = "";
      bool begin = false;

      while (client.available() || !begin) {
        char c = client.read();

        if (c == '{') {
          begin = true;
        }
        if (begin) response += (c);
        if (c == '"}') {
          break;
        }
        delay(1);
      }
      int start = response.indexOf("status\":\"") + 11;
      int end = start + 3;
      response_Status = response.substring(start, end);

      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);

      if (!root.success())
      {
        Serial.print("parseObject(");
        Serial.print(response);
        Serial.println(") failed");
        break;
      }

      Serial.println(response_Status);
      if (response_Status == "200") {

        Serial.println("200");
        boxOpenend = true;

        while (boxOpenend) {

          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("Box openend ,press");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print(" * to close");

          myservo.write(0);// rotate the servo to open
          delay(175);

          char key = customKeypad.getKey();   // get the key pressed
          //value = value + String(key);

          if (key == '*') {
            myservo.write(90); // rotate the servo to lock
            value = "";                           // clear the string
            boxOpenend = false;

          }
          // box gaat terug toe maar ik blijf in deze loop zitten want lcd scherm blijft staan op "Box geopend , druk * om te sluiten
        }

      }
      else if (response_Status != "200") {

        Serial.println("not 200");

        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("wrong code or");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("already deliverd");

        delay(175);
        value = "";
        exit;
      }
      //hier net hetzelfde
      break ;
    }
    // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
    if (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
      client.stop();

      // do nothing forevermore:
      while (true);
    }
    exit;
  }

  if (customKey == '*') {
    myservo.write(90);                   // rotate the servo to lock
    value = "";                           // clear the string
  }

  delay(175); // for optimal lcd screen view
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

This is where the code get's stuck. 
It keeps on showing box opened press  * to close.
even when I press * and the box closes it keeps on saying this

```
while (boxOpenend) {

          lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("Box openend ,press");
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print(" * to close");

          myservo.write(0);// rotate the servo to open
          delay(175);

          char key = customKeypad.getKey();   // get the key pressed
          //value = value + String(key);

          if (key == '*') {
            myservo.write(90); // rotate the servo to lock
            value = "";                           // clear the string
            boxOpenend = false;

          }
          // box gaat terug toe maar ik blijf in deze loop zitten want lcd scherm blijft staan op "Box geopend , druk * om te sluiten
        }

      }
```

It might have a simple solution that I'm just not thinking of but it really bothers me!

UPDATE , We made a little progress as to figuring out why it wont work. the code that we are running now is:

```
/* hardware libraries*/
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>

/*Wifi and request libraries*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW 0x0

/* wifi credentials*/
char ssid[] = "XXXXXXX";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "XXXXXXX";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char server[] = "parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu";
// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); // lcd object
Servo myservo; //servo object
boolean boxOpenend = false ;

/* Keypad*/
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7};

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
String value = "";

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(); //start lcd
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(A0); // attach servo to pin
  lcd.backlight(); // start screen light

  /* connect to wifi */
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
}

void loop() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Geef bestelcode");

  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();   // get the key pressed
  value = value + String(customKey);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(value);


  if (customKey == '#') 
  {
  Serial.println("PRESSED #");
    String response_Status = "";
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

  Serial.println("RESULT OF CLIENT.CONNECT()");
  Serial.println(client.connect(server, 80));

    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (client.connect(server, 80) == 1) 
  {
    Serial.println("IK BEN HIER");
    value.remove(4);
    Serial.println(value);
    Serial.println("connected to server");

    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /api/boxes/1444/pin/" + value + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("client.connect() not successfull");
  }

    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonBuffer;

    if (client.connected()) 
  {
    Serial.println("CLIENT CONNECTED");

    String response = "";
    bool begin = false;

    while (client.available() || !begin) {
      char c = client.read();

      if (c == '{') {
        begin = true;
      }

      if (begin) {
        response += (c);
      }

      if (c == '"}') {
        break;
      }

      delay(1);
    }

    int start = response.indexOf("status\":\"") + 11;
    int end = start + 3;

    response_Status = response.substring(start, end);
    Serial.println(response_Status);

    // response successfull
    if (response_Status == "200")
    {
      Serial.println("RESPONSE 200");
      Serial.println("response state == 200");

      // First open the box
      // 0° means open
      Serial.println("OPEN BOX");
      myservo.write(0);
      delay(175);

      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("                ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Box opened ,press");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("                ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(" * to close");
    }
    else 
    {
      Serial.println("RESPONSE NOT 200");
      Serial.println("not 200");

      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Foute code of");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("al afgeleverd");

      delay(175);
    }
    }

  // reset the value
  value = "";
  }

  // lock box and reset value
  if (customKey == '*') 
  {
    Serial.println("CLOSE BOX");
    myservo.write(90); 
    value = "";
    client.stop();
  }

  delay(175); // for optimal lcd screen view
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

this is the serial output:
[image: serial output]

it's clear that the first request the check the code goes thru but when you try a second time it comes out empty. We did some research and we found that in some cases the servo could affect the request in a bad way. Just not sure if that is correct and how to fix this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103266/discussion-on-question-by-imkevr-arduino-uno-wifi-rev2-stuck-inside-loop).

Answer (score 2):

```
/* hardware libraries*/
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>

/*Wifi and request libraries*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW 0x0

/* wifi credentials*/
char ssid[] = "sidd";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "pass";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char server[] = "parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu";
// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); // lcd object
Servo myservo; //servo object
boolean boxOpenend = false ;

/* Keypad*/
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7};

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
String value = "";

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(); //start lcd
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(A0); // attach servo to pin
  lcd.backlight(); // start screen light

  /* connect to wifi */
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  /*
    // check for the WiFi module:
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
      Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
      // don't continue
      while (true);
    }

    String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
    if (fv < "1.0.0") {
      Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
    }

    // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
    while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
      // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
      status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

      // wait 10 seconds for connection:
      delay(10000);
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to wifi");*/
  createConnection();
}

void loop() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Bestelcode / pin");

  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();   // get the key pressed
  value = value + String(customKey);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(value);


  if (customKey == '#')
  {
    createConnection();
    Serial.println("PRESSED #");
    String response_Status = "";
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

    Serial.println("RESULT OF CLIENT.CONNECT()");
    Serial.println(client.connect(server, 80));

    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (client.connect(server, 80) == 1)
    { 
      int valueLen = value.length();
      if(valueLen == 5){
      Serial.println("IK BEN een pin ");
      value.remove(4);
      Serial.println(value);
      Serial.println("connected to server");

      // Make a HTTP request:
      client.println("GET /api/boxes/2025/pin/" + value + " HTTP/1.1");//1444
      client.println("Host: parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
      }
      if(valueLen ==17){
      Serial.println("IK BEN een bestelcode");
      value.remove(16);
      Serial.println(value);
      Serial.println("connected to server");

      // Make a HTTP request:
      client.println("GET /api/boxes/2025/code/" + value + " HTTP/1.1");//1444
      client.println("Host: parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();

        }
        else{

          Serial.println("invalid amount of numbers code");
          /*lcd.clear();
          lcd.print("ongeldige code");*/

          }
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("client.connect() not successfull");
    }

    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonBuffer;

    if (client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("CLIENT CONNECTED");

      String response = "";
      bool begin = false;

      while (client.available() || !begin) {
        char c = client.read();

        if (c == '{') {
          begin = true;
        }

        if (begin) {
          response += (c);
        }

        if (c == '"}') {
          break;
        }

        delay(1);
      }

      int start = response.indexOf("status\":\"") + 11;
      int end = start + 3;

      response_Status = response.substring(start, end);
      Serial.println(response_Status);

      // response successfull
      if (response_Status == "200")
      {
        Serial.println("RESPONSE 200");
        Serial.println("response state == 200");

        // First open the box
        // 0° means open
        Serial.println("OPEN BOX");
        myservo.write(0);
        delay(175);

        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("                ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Box open ,druk");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("                ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("* om te sluiten");
        delay(5000);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("RESPONSE NOT 200");
        Serial.println("not 200");

        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Foute code of");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("al geleverd");

        delay(2500);
      }
    }

    // reset the value
    value = "";
  }

  // lock box and reset value
  if (customKey == '*')
  {
    Serial.println("CLOSE BOX");
    myservo.write(90);
    value = "";
    client.stop();
  }

  delay(175); // for optimal lcd screen view
}
void createConnection() {

  // This new line is required to disconnect the previous connection otherwise
  // it will try to use the old connection and never reconnect if the connection fails
  status = WiFi.disconnect();

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10);
  }
  // you're connected now, so print out the status:
  printWifiStatus();

}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

I had to rewrite my wifi connection into a function outside my setup. Because the program only established a connection in the beginning and closed it after my first request. By giving it it's own function I could call it inside my loop whenever the user would enter a code the program could reestablish a connection. My program now runs how I need it to run.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can not verify my code, I tried to modify your program. Probably it does not compile and you have to do some corrections. I changed it in a way I would expect it to work and hopefully I understood your intentions.

At least we could use this version as a base to elaborate a working one together.

```
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW 0x0

char ssid[] = "ssid";
char pass[] = "password";
int keyIndex = 0;

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char server[] = "parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu";

WiFiClient client;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
Servo myservo;

/* Keypad*/
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {3, 4, 5, 6};
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7};

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
String value = "";

void setup() 
{
  lcd.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(A0);
  lcd.backlight();

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) 
  {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") { Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware"); }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
}

void loop() 
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Geef bestelcode");
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  value = value + String(customKey);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(value);
  if (customKey == '#') 
  {
    String response_Status = "";
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

    if ( client.connect( server, 80 ) ) 
    {
      value.remove(16);
      Serial.println(value);
      Serial.println("connected to server");

      // Make a HTTP request:
      client.println("GET /api/boxes/1444/code/" + value + " HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: parcelbox.1819.caro.deweze.nxtmediatech.eu");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      client.println();
    }

    StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonBuffer;

    if ( client.connected() ) 
    {
      String response = "";
      bool begin = false;

      // I do not understand why you have to use  || ! begin 
      // If the client has no content available, you can not read some
      // It doesn't matter if begin is true or false. 
      // Or am I missing something?
      while ( client.available() || ! begin ) 
      {
        char c = client.read();

        if ( c == '{' )  { begin = true;    }
        if ( begin )     { response += (c); }
        if ( c == '"}' ) { break;           }

        delay(1);
      }

      // Why do you parse the json text for a special 
      // attribute and then parse it again into a json object
      // where you can read this attribute?
      int start = response.indexOf("status\":\"") + 11;
      int end = start + 3;
      response_Status = response.substring(start, end);

// I commented this out because you do not use the root variable 
// in the following code
//      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response);
//      if (!root.success())
//      {
//        Serial.print("parseObject(");
//        Serial.print(response);
//        Serial.println(") failed");
//        break;
//      }

      Serial.println(response_Status);
      if (response_Status == "200") 
      {
        Serial.println("response state == 200");

        // First open the box

        // 0° means open
        myservo.write(0);
        delay(175);

        // Then inform the user how to close it

        lcd.clear();
        // I added the cursor positioning.
        // As far as I know clear does not reset the cursor.
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Box openend ,press");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(" * to close");

        // then check if the user wants to close it
        char key;
        do 
        {
          key = customKeypad.getKey();
          if (key == '*') 
          {
            // 90° means locked
            myservo.write(90);
            value = "";
          }
        }
        while( key != '*' );

      }
      else
      {
      // I replaced the else if by a simple if
      // as (response_Status != "200") is the else case
      // of (response_Status == "200")
        Serial.println("response state != 200");

        lcd.clear();
        // "set cursor" added
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("wrong code or");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("already deliverd");

        delay(175);
        value = "";
      }
      // I change the while loop into an if block
      // so you don't need a break; here
    }

// Here you could enter a halt state without a reason.
// Even you won't expect to halt here.
//    if (!client.connected()) 
//    {
//      Serial.println();
//      Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
//      client.stop();
//
//      // do nothing forevermore:
//      while (true);
//    }
  }

  if (customKey == '*') 
  {
    // 90° means locked
    myservo.write(90); 
    value = "";     
  }

  // for optimal lcd screen view
  delay(175);
}

void printWifiStatus() 
{
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

**EDIT**

This edit is related to the updated version of your program.

If you close the box with a key press you also stop the client with the last line.

Please remove the following line from the program.

```
// lock box and reset value
if (customKey == '*') 
{
  Serial.println("CLOSE BOX");
  myservo.write(90); 
  value = "";
  // remove this as you can not connect a stopped client
  // client.stop();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code it builds perfectly, I could open the box and close it but the LCD keeps displaying " box open press * to close ". Your code is much more readable and structured than mine! I can learn alot from this

Comment: Thank you for the reply and extending your question. By looking at my code I saw that I made a terrible mistake. Perhaps I've programed with JavaScript for too long now. In JS "" and '' is the same. In C/C++ Its something completely different. The line `while( key != "*" )` is always true and the Loop is never left. I've corrected it in  my answer. `while( key != '*' )`.  Could you please change it in your program too and try that version.

Comment: @imkeVr I just realize that, you use a complete different code now.  And it would be better if I had looked into the output earlier.;-) I don't believe the the Server disturbed the client communication. I think you are simply not able to open a connection with a client that is stopped. I'll update the answer once more. ;-)

Comment: I found the a way that works for my program. I scratched the wifi setup in the void setup en relocated it to its own function outside any loop or setup. This way I could call for the function and reestablish a connection inside my void loop itself. It now works like it should. Thank you for all the help I learned alot by doing this!

Comment: @imkeVr It was a pleasure to work with you. I first wanted to propose what you have done now by yourself, but I didn't want to make my answer too complicated. And now I see you managed it, just with the few information i gave you. This is one of the moments, that keeps me answering questions on SE. And I could imagine that, if you keep on learning quickly, our conversation in the future would be with changed rolls. I ask and you answer. I wish you and your partner success with the project.